# How can I create target for debug as well as default target for building program normally while creating makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gdb

I am writing makefile to build my program.

I want to know commands for debug.

I have written makefile for compile and clean

```
all: perfect.c
    gcc -g -o perfect perfect.c
clean:
    rm -f perfect
```

Can you help me in writing for debug? and what does it mean default target?

Comment: You cannot do anything with Make if you do not know how to do it *without* Make. You must read about debug versions, and perhaps gdb, the GNU debugger.

Comment: -1. Do home work first http://sagarsakre.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed study the basics about make files. You can start with [this link](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html)

```
Can you help me in writing for debug?
```

Already your make file is written for debug (using -g compiler flag)

```
 what does it mean default target?
```

Default target is your first target. In your case (and most of the cases) it is `all` that is if you just invoke `make` then what rule has to be executed. See to clean you have to give `make clean` but for taget `all` you can call `make all` or just `make`. Since `all` is the first target it will be executed by default. If you write `clean` at the beginning then `clean` becomes the default target.

Lets rewrite your `makefile` for normal building and debug building.

```
all: perfect.c
     gcc -o perfect perfect.c
debug: perfect.c
      gcc -g -o perfect-debug perfect.c
clean:
      rm -rf perfect perfect-debug
```

So if you run `make all` or just `make` `perfect.c` will be built without debug option. If you run `make debug` then `perfect.c` will be built with debug option.